# Render component based on a variable - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I would like to ask, if its possible to return a component based on a variable, my idea if this is possible:

```
var location = this.props.location // Eg. Asia,Australia
<location+"HeaderComponent" />
```

My problem with this is I need to manually import all of my components individually.

This is other script that I have:

```
import AsiaHeaderComponent from "components/AsiaHeaderComponent.jsx";
import AustraliaHeaderComponent from "components/AustraliaHeaderComponent.jsx";

class Home extends React.Component {
    renderHeader(){
        if(this.props.location == "Asia"){
            return (
                <AsiaHeaderComponent />
            );
        }
        else if(this.props.location == "Australia"){
            return (
                <AustraliaHeaderComponent />
            );
        }
    }
    render(){
        return (
            { this.renderHeader() }
        )
    }
}
```

Same with above I need to manually import all of the header that will be put inside if else condition.

is there a way to efficiently do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import AsiaHeaderComponent from "components/AsiaHeaderComponent.jsx";
import AustraliaHeaderComponent from "components/AustraliaHeaderComponent.jsx";

const componentOf = {
 aisa: AsiaHeaderComponent,
 australia: AustraliaHeaderComponent
};

class Home extends React.Component {
    renderHeader(){
     return componentOf[this.props.location]
    }
    render(){
        return (
            { this.renderHeader() }
        )
    }
}
```

maybe this is a little bit better?

Comment: How come this is the accepted answer, it doesn't work for me, while John's answer does

Answer (score 6):

Two things. you should first only have one header and pass it the data it needs to render what it needs to render. I'm assuming the header is probably not going to be that much different from one continent to another. Secondly.. That being said a way to dynamically get components is to use a hash table like so

```
const headerLookup = {
    asia: AsiaHeaderComponent,
    australia: AustraliaHeaderComponent
    .... more here
}
```

then your code

```
render() {
    const Header = headerLookup[this.props.location.toLowerCase()]

    return (
        <Header {...someprops} />
    );
}
```

In theory you should be able to take all of your components / elements in the header and make them be extendable based off of a type. that type being the continent name. If you want a better or more full example it would help a lot to see what you have in your header component currently so I can see commonalities between them :)

Comment: Yeah Thanks Man! I just follow your suggestion and it looks like this will work for me now.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I'd probably go about it, import all locations into one component, do your logic there

```
import AsiaHeaderComponent from "components/AsiaHeaderComponent.jsx";
import AustraliaHeaderComponent from "components/AustraliaHeaderComponent.jsx";

class Home extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const {continent} = this.props;


        return (
            <div>
                {continent == 'Asia' ?
                     <AsiaHeaderComponent { ...this.props} />:null
                }
                {location == 'Australia' ?
                     <AustraliaHeaderComponent { ...this.props}  />:null
                }

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home
```

you can then  import location and use it

```
import Home from "components/Home.jsx";

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {

    render(){
        return (
            <Home { ...this.props} location={SomeLocation} />
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

***ECMAScript 6 module loader API*** :

Apart from declarative syntax for working with modules you can load them programmatically but `" ECMAScript 6 module loader API "` is work in progress.

> Note :
>
> 1. The module loader API is not part of the ES6 standard.
> 2. The module loader API is work in progress

The ways you can achieve this are :

- Programmatically work with modules
- Configure module loading.

You can programmatically import a module, via an API based on Promises:

```
  System.import('some_module')
    .then(some_module => {
        // Use some_module
    })
    .catch(error => {
        ···
    });
```

System.import() enables you to:

- Use modules inside  elements (where module syntax is not
  supported, consult the section on modules versus scripts for
  details).
- Load modules conditionally.

System.import() retrieves a single module, you can use Promise.all() to import **several modules**:

```
Promise.all(
    ['module1', 'module2', 'module3']
    .map(x => System.import(x)))
.then(([module1, module2, module3]) => {
    // Use module1, module2, module3
});
```

> There are few more ways to achieve it please refer this link
>   [ECMAScript 6 module loader API](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html) look for topic at 16.5