# Render React component from array values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on React with Symfony API and when I connect to my app, I've got a role defined by Symfony

It returns this if I'm an admin : `["ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN"]`

It returns this if I'm a moderator : `["ROLE_USER", "ROLE_MODERATOR"]`

It returns this if I'm a user : `["ROLE_USER"]`

Currently my code is working fine and if I'm a user, it shows the user view, if I'm a moderator it shows the moderator view etc.
So my question is : **Is there a better way to create a condition that will render the good component in function of my user role ?**

```js
render()
  {
      let content = "";
      if (this.props.auth.user.roles.includes("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
          content = <NavAdminDashboard />;
      } else if (this.props.auth.user.roles.includes("ROLE_MODERATOR")) {
          content = <NavModeratorDashboard />;
      } else {
          content = <NavUserDashboard />;
      }

      return (
          <Fragment>
              {content}
          </Fragment>
      )
  }
```

I have checked this : [Render component based on a variable - reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42363698/render-component-based-on-a-variable-reactjs)

It is better than my code but it only works if my roles render as string and not as array like my code.

Comment: IMO what you have written is proper way of doing, later on when you need some condition checks than it will be easy to handle with such structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in two ways

The first one is a little cleaner.

```
render(){
    const {roles} = this.props.auth.user;

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            { roles.include("ROLE_ADMIN") && <NavAdminDashboard /> }
            { roles.include("ROLE_MODERATOR") && <NavModeratorDashboard  /> }
            { !roles.include("ROLE_ADMIN") && !roles.include("ROLE_MODERATOR) && <NavUserDashboard  /> }
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

You can also do that by creating two methods `isAdmin` and `isModerator`:

```
isAdmin = () => {
    return this.props.auth.user.roles.include("ROLE_ADMIN");
}

isModerator = () => {
    return this.props.auth.user.roles.include("ROLE_MODERATOR");
}

render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            { this.isAdmin() && <NavAdminDashboard /> }
            { this.isModerator() && <NavModeratorDashboard  /> }
            { !this.isAdmin() && !this.isModerator() && <NavUserDashboard  /> }
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Or you can add a `isUser` method to check if its only user

```
isUser = () => {
    const {roles} = this.props.auth.user;
    return roles.include("ROLE_USER") && roles.length === 1;
}

render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            { this.isAdmin() && <NavAdminDashboard /> }
            { this.isModerator() && <NavModeratorDashboard  /> }
            { this.isUser() && <NavUserDashboard  /> }
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for the delay, I'm from France haha. I think that'll be easier from what I did, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I think your code is fine and doesn't necessary need to change. But I  personally move the role logic either to external functions (that can be unit tested) or methods on the component. Eg:

```
get isAdmin() {
  return this.props.roles.include('ADMIN');
}

get isUser() {
  return !this.props.roles.some(role => role !== 'USER');
}

render() {
  return <>
    {this.isAdmin && <Admin />}
    {this.isUser && <User />}
  </>
}
```

Another alternative is to move the parsing of roles to a helper function and map the array to props. Eg:

```
<Component isAdmin={hasAdminRole(roles)} />
```

Both of these are nicer solutions if you ask me. But in the end, as long as the code works it might be good enough. You can always go back and refactor later.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for the delay, I'm from France haha. The answer of "Ertan Hasani" was the solution I expected (don't know why I didn't think of this idea) but you're answer is also really nice, +1 :)